# dynamically generating the nodes in treeview control and displaying the results on selecting the node in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, sql, treeview

I am using a treeview control and just want to add nodes dynamically.On selecting a node the
results based on that node must be shown below.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you set the TreeView to dynamically add the child nodes using Ajax.

```
var tree = new TreeView()
{
  PopulateNodesFromClient = true,
  EnableClientScript = true
};

tree.TreeNodePopulate += (s, e) => 
{
  var childItems = CallTheDB(e.Node.Value); //Get the children for the parent node
  foreach(var item in childItems)
  {
     e.Node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode()
     {
       PopulateOnDemand = true,
       Text = item.Text,
       Value = item.Key,
       SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Expand
     });
  }
};
```